# Pyspark - Lastest record by user and summarize results

Tags: pyspark, summarization

Can you think of an easier way to achieve this result?

In this case, I summarize the results for each 'id'.
The idea is to bring the last value and the total per user.

Thank you very much!

```
tmp= spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, '2020-02-17',10), 
        (1, '2020-02-16',14),
        (1, '2020-02-15',19),
        (2, '2020-02-17',15),
        (2, '2020-02-19',9),
    ],
    ['id','date','value'] 
)

tmp.createOrReplaceTempView('tmp_sql')

ver_sum = spark.sql("""
                SELECT id, 
                       value                       
                FROM tmp_sql as t
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT *
                  FROM tmp_sql AS witness
                  WHERE witness.id = t.id AND witness.date > t.date
                )
""")

ver_sum.createOrReplaceTempView('ver_sum_sql')


spark.sql(""" select a.id,
                     a.value as last_value,
                     sum(b.value) as tot_value

              from ver_sum_sql a
                  join tmp_sql b on a.id = b.id
              group by 1,2
         """).show()

+---+----------+---------+
| id|last_value|tot_value|
+---+----------+---------+
|  1|        10|       43|
|  2|         9|       24|
+---+----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you frequently need this information up to date, you could create a table with these columns (i.e. id, last_value, tot_value) and update this table with a trigger on original table.

If you want to keep the work on queries, then consider changing `SELECT *` to `SELECT 1` for the first query, for a better performance, because this subquery is only for filtering, not for selecting all the columns (though a good optimizer would optimize it automatically, but change it just in case).

I'm not sure about the performance of the next tip, but in the second query you can first find the sum of values and then join the results (otherwise the result of join is a big temporary data), so you might try

```sql
select lastv.id    as id,
       lastv.value as last_value,
       sumv.sum    as tot_value
from ver_sum_sql as lastv
join (
    select id, sum(value) as sum
    from tmp_sql
    group by id
) as sumv
on lastv.id = sumv.id
```